# C sockets: getsocketnane ip address is always 0.0.0.0

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Hi i am programming a networking client in c and i am using the getsocketname function to return the IP and port of the socket i have created but for some reason the IP is always returned as 0.0.0.0 here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> //include standard input/output library
#include <stdlib.h> //include standard libraries
#include <string.h> //include string headers 
#include <unistd.h> //add definitions for constansts and functions 
#include <sys/types.h> // include definitions for different data types
#include <sys/socket.h> //include socket support
#include <netinet/in.h> //define internet protocol functions
#include <arpa/inet.h> //define internet protocol functions
#include "Practical.h" //include practical header file

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char myIP[16];
unsigned int myPort;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,myaddr;

  if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) // Test for correct number of arguments
    DieWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)",
        "<Server Address> <Echo Word> [<Server Port>]");

  char *servIP = argv[1];     // First arg: server IP address (dotted quad)
  char *echoString = argv[2]; // Second arg: string to echo

  // Third arg (optional): server port (numeric).  7 is well-known echo port
  in_port_t servPort = (argc == 4) ? atoi(argv[3]) : 7;  //21



 // Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP  //23
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);//this block of code creates a reliable tcp stream socket and checks what the returned integer is from the socket function, the returned function will give a integer that descibes the socket. if this is 0 then kill the socket and show the user an error message.
  if (sock < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("socket() failed"); //26

  // Construct the server address structure //28
  struct sockaddr_in servAddr;            // Server address
  memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr)); // Zero out structure
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;          // IPv4 address family
  // Convert address
  int rtnVal = inet_pton(AF_INET, servIP, &servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
  if (rtnVal == 0)
    DieWithUserMessage("inet_pton() failed", "invalid address string");
  else if (rtnVal < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("inet_pton() failed");
  servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);    // Server port
  myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK;

bzero(&myaddr,sizeof(myaddr));
int len = sizeof(myaddr);
getsockname(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &myaddr, &len);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &myaddr.sin_addr, myIP, sizeof(myIP));
myPort = ntohs(myaddr.sin_port);

printf("local ip address : %s\n", myIP);
printf("local port: %u\n", myPort);

  // Establish the connection to the echo server
  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithSystemMessage("connect() failed"); 

  size_t echoStringLen = strlen(echoString); // Determine input length //44

  // Send the string to the server
  ssize_t numBytes = send(sock, echoString, echoStringLen, 0);
  if (numBytes < 0) //sending string to server, number of bytes of the message is equal to return value of send function, if the number of bytes is less than 0 then do not send and say to user that the send failed
    DieWithSystemMessage("send() failed");
  else if (numBytes != echoStringLen)
    DieWithUserMessage("send()", "sent unexpected number of bytes"); //51

// if the number of bytes is not equal to the input length of the string parsed as an argument then die with the message to the user saying sent unexpected number of bytes.

  // Receive the same string back from the server  //53
  unsigned int totalBytesRcvd = 0; // Count of total bytes received
  fputs("Received: ", stdout);     // Setup to print the echoed string
  while (totalBytesRcvd < echoStringLen) {
    char buffer[BUFSIZE]; // I/O buffer
    /* Receive up to the buffer size (minus 1 to leave space for
     a null terminator) bytes from the sender */
    numBytes = recv(sock, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
    if (numBytes < 0)
      DieWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    else if (numBytes == 0)
      DieWithUserMessage("recv()", "connection closed prematurely");
    totalBytesRcvd += numBytes; // Keep tally of total bytes
    buffer[numBytes] = '\0';    // Terminate the string!
    fputs(buffer, stdout);      // Print the echo buffer

  }

  fputc('\n', stdout); // Print a final linefeed //70


  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}
//closing off connections to clean up data left over.
```

the port number returned is always 0 too, i am assigning the address of the myaddr struct to be loopback address so i believe it is supposed to return 127.0.0.1 as the IP but it isn't, i am sort of new to socket programming so my logic might not be perfect, i just cant see whats wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the socket hasn't been bound to a local address yet.

You need to get the local address *after* it has been bound, which happens automatically with the `connect` call.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. if I move my code to get the local IP after the connect function is called it prints out blank for the IP address and 0 for the port

Comment: I fixed it, it's just me being stupid. I was trying to print the values out before the getsockname was called. thanks for your help!